# Importing submodules

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and i m having a really bad time to overcome a problem with the importing system.

Lets say i have the file system presented below:

```
/src    
/src/main.py     
/src/submodules/   
/src/submodules/submodule.py   
/src/submodules/subsubmodules   
/src/submodules/subsubmodules/subsubmodule.py
```

All the folders (src, submodules, subsubmodules) have and empty `__init__.py` file.

In submodule.py i have:

```
from subsubmodules import subsubmodule
```

In main.py i have:

```
from submodules import submodule
```

When i run submodule.py python accepts the import. But when i run main.py python raises error for the import of subsubmodule.py because /src/submodules/subsubmodules/ folder is not in the path.

Only solution is to change the import of submodule.py to

```
  from submodules.subsubmodules import subsubmodule
```

This seems to me as an awful solution because after that i cannot run submodule.py and i m sure that something else is the key to that.

An other solution is to add the following code to the `__init__.py` file:

```
import os
import sys
import inspect


cmd_subfolder = os.path.split(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))[0]
if cmd_subfolder not in sys.path:
     sys.path.insert(0, cmd_subfolder)
```

Is there any way to do this using just the importing system of python and not other methods that do it manually using, for example sys.path or other modules like os, inspect etc..?

How can i import modules without caring about the modules they import?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `subsubmodule.py` as

```
python3 -m submodule.subsubmodules.subsubmodule
```

If you want a shorter way to invoke it, you're free to add a shell or Python script for that on the top level of your package.

This is how imports work in Python 3; [there are reasons for that](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this issue by using `sys.path` in your program.

```
sys.path.insert(0, './lib')
import subsubmodule
```

For this code, you can put all your imports to a `lib` folder.

You can read the [official documentation on Python packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) where this is explained in depth.